# Move Files using Kill in Visual Basic 

Tags: vb.net

I am making a desktop cleaner and I want the program to search For files extensions and move them into a new folder each named after the extension name.  Here is what I have.

```
Public Class Form2


Private Sub Form_Load()

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim MyFolderBrowser As New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = MyFolderBrowser.ShowDialog()

    Me.FileReference.Text = MyFolderBrowser.SelectedPath
End Sub



Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Label1.Text = "Cleaned."
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill(Me.FileReference.Text("\*.txt"))
        If Not Directory.Exists(FileReference.Text) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FileReference.Text)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

I want to use `Kill(Me.FileReference.Text("\*.txt"))` to move the files with .txt extention in the Directory which the textbox named `Filereference.text` contains which is extracted using `MyFolderBrowser.SelectedPath`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, _
    FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")

    Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(foundFile, "C:\StorageDir\" & foundFileInfo.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer But How do I use (FileReference.text)(TextBox) SO the user selects the folder instead of the progam selecting it for example how i use it Instead of "C:\StorageDir\" @See-Sharp